# How can I send and receive a large file over HTTP in C#

Tags: c#, http, getresponse

I am working on developing an HTTP Server/Client and I can currently send small files over it such as .txt files and other easy to read files that do not require much memory. However when I want to send a larger file say a .exe or large .pdf I get memory errors. This are occurring from the fact that before I try to send or receive a file I have to specify the size of my byte[] buffer. Is there a way to get the size of the buffer while reading it from stream?

I want to do something like this:

```
//Create the stream.
private Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

//read bytes from stream into buffer.
byte[] byteArray = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(dataStream.Length)];
dataStream.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.Length);
```

However when calling "dataStream.Length" it throws the error:

```
 ExceptionError: This stream does not support seek operations.
```

Can someone offer some advice as to how I can get the length of my byte[] from the stream?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CopyTo` method of the *stream*.

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
dataStream.CopyTo(m);
byte[] byteArray = m.ToArray();
```

You can also write directly to file

```
var fs = File.Create("....");
dataStream.CopyTo(fs);
```

Answer (score 1):

The network layer has no way of knowing how long the response stream is.

However, the server is supposed to tell you how long it is; look in the `Content-Length` response header.
If that header is missing or incorrect, you're out of luck; you'll need to keep reading until you run out of data.